# different child layout for each Group header in ExpandableListview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have used `ExpandableListview`  in which every `Group` has same `child layout`.

Now there is a situation , in which every `Group` has different child layout (some has `checkbox`, some has `imageview`, some has `textview`) depending upon its values fetched from web service

How do I modify My previous `ExpandableListAdapter`  that has same `child layout`

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
        }

        CheckBox chkListChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_child_chkbox);



        chkListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.e("groupPosition", "kargr "+groupPosition);

            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();


    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);              

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        View ind = convertView.findViewById( R.id.explist_indicator);
        if( ind != null ) {
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView)ind;
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1 : 0) ;
                Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
                drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }


        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming not changing your current code more than is required, a correct implementation will be a pretty decent refactor, you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(("IMAGE HEADER").equals(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))){
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_image, null);
        //update your views here
    }else if(("CHECKBOX HEADER").equals(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))){
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_image, null);
        //update your views here
    }
    //etc
    return convertView;       
}
```

As you can see, this will get messy fast, and doesn't properly recycle views so it'll be harder on memory. It also requires you to hard-code strings for headers.

A better way to do this is to create a base Class (instead of String) that has information about the View type and how to render the View as a child of the group. Each of your types would inherit from this base Class. E.g.: TypeCheckbox extends TypeListItem.

And then your constructor would look like:

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<TypeListItem>> listChildData) {
    ...
}
```

Expect things to get complicated when you're trying to display more than one type of item in any type of CollectionView.